# Activity's status bar color is different for no apparent reason

Tags: android, xml, statusbar

I've created a new activity and for some reason, when it is used, it uses a different color in the status bar. What's strange is that in the "design" preview it renders the correct color.

Below are two screen shots, the darker color is the correct color.

**Incorrect**
[image]
**Correct**
[image]

The themes are the same as the other .xml layouts, so I'm having trouble really figuring out where this error is coming from. Below is the code for the layout:

**activity_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.brewguide.android.coffeebrewguide.MenuActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/myfragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I'm not sure what other code would be useful to include for diagnosing this.

---

### **Edit:**

**styles.xml**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="DescriptionTextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/mainBackground</item>
</style>

<!--style for the start button in the clock view layout-->
<style name="AppTheme.Button.Start" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/complimentaryLeft</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/cardview_dark_background</item>
</style>

<!--style for the stop button in the clock view layout-->
<style name="AppTheme.Button.Stop" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/cardview_dark_background</item>
</style>

<!--style for the reset button in the clock view layout-->
<style name="AppTheme.Button.Reset" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/cardview_light_background</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="spinBars">true</item>
    <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Share your `styles.xml`.

Comment: @azizbekian just added to the question

Comment: Also share `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to programatically set the color using the following line:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
```

I would prefer to have this done in the .xml however.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. For me it was an issue with a second styles.xml file (still not sure why I had two). The specific line that was causing the issue was:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

I don't see this in your posted styles.xml, but perhaps it will help someone else.

Comment: This resolved my issue. I had that line on my style.xml(v21) file

Answer (score 2):

Check your `colors.xml` for color named `primary_dark` and change it to be the same to `primary`, because Android use that(primary_dark) color to colorize status bar.

Comment: Changed `colorPrimaryDark` to `primary.` didn't do anything :/

Comment: @JohnSnow post your colors.xml please